# changing font size if on an iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone

I want to check if I'm not using an Ipad and if so change the font size in a div #txtArea.  I have the following code but it doesn't work:

```
 <script>if ($(window).width() < 600) { $('#txtArea').attr('font-size:60px'); }</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Font-size is style, not an attribute so you need to use [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method to change it:

```
   $('#txtArea').css('font-size', '60px');
```

Note that it may be better to use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FMedia_queries) based on width instead of script code.

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #txtArea {
    font-size:60px;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks,but I would like to use your css method.  I've typed:

Comment: <script>if ($(window).width() < 600) { $('#txtArea').css('font-size',    '60px');} </script>  but it doesn't do anything.  Any ideas?

Comment: And I have this: #txtArea {font-size:30px} in the head as the start up.  After the javascript above it stays at 30 on the iphone simulator

Comment: @user2998021 have you tried to debug the issue? I'm not sure how to debug on iPhone emulator, but desktop webKit-based browsers can often be used to debug such issues. I'd recommend first trying code in your desktop browser and using dev tools (Chrome/IE/Firefox - F12) to debug. It could be as simple as putting script before HTML is actually rendered on the page, but it is not possible to say without actual sample.